# Errors on edits are not very descriptive

Tags: discussion

Several times, I've tried to edit a question on SO, and instead of getting an error that correctly describes why my edit cannot be applied, I get this somewhat confusing dialog:

> Edits must be at least 6 characters;
>   is there something else to improve in this post?

[image]

However, usually, the edit I was proposing could be more than 6 characters long.

I get that someone could already be editing it, or that some edit is queued to be reviewed. But it would be better stated as either of the above — or any other more descriptive message — than the "6 characters long" message. That sometimes leaves me wondering whether to magically add other characters just to make up the edit length.

Comment: Did you add more than 6 characters in the edit? The dialog doesn't seem that confusing to me. Basically a edit that changes less than 6 characters probably doesn't improve the post that much.

Comment: @SpencerWieczorek, usually the edit is at least up to 6 characters, as is required, but I keep getting the error.

Comment: Then in this case can you show us the edit compared to the original?

Comment: Well, this is a real case, and the original has now been edited (by someone else), so I can't get it back the way it was when I tried editing. However, bottomline is, the code lacked proper formatting, and that was what my edit attempted to fix.

Comment: If your characters are just indenting code, that doesn't count toward the 6 characters you need by the way. So if that's the case, that error message is correct, it's just that you didn't have a way of knowing whitespace doesn't count.

Comment: @Kendra, never knew that until now. Thank you.

Answer (score 4):

I agree the error could be more descriptive (mentioning that whitespace doesn't count, for instance), but in this case, it is correct. From a comment you posted on this question:

> However, bottomline is, the code lacked proper formatting, and that was what my edit attempted to fix.

Whitespace used to indent code *does not* count toward the 6 character limit. Instead of just formatting the code, try to find grammatical errors in the post that you can also edit. There are often, even in well-written posts, at least a few small typos or grammatical errors you can make.

For instance, in the picture you provided, the last paragraph reads:

> I get this error: Incorrect integer value: '' for column 'id' at row 1
>   Does someone how to fix?

To get the six characters, you could have moved the error onto its own line and formatted it:

> I get this error:
>   `Incorrect integer value '' for column 'id' at row 1`
>   Does someone how to fix?

You then could have fixed the grammar in the last sentence:

> I get this error:
>   `Incorrect integer value '' for column 'id' at row 1`
>   Does someone know how to fix this?

Or you could have re-written the last sentence:

> I get this error:
>   `Incorrect integer value '' for column 'id' at row 1`
>   What can I do to fix this error?

And those are just things you can do with what we can see- There was likely more above the code that you could have edited as well. While formatting code is very important, unformatted code and be a signal that there's more wrong with the post in terms of grammar or spelling issues. (This is of course not always the case, but it should make you take a second look.) If there really is nothing else to fix, a 2k+ editor can always fix the code without hitting this error.

When suggesting edits, try to fix as much as possible. Not only does this make it more likely that your edit will be accepted, it will also help improve the post more. Doing this *also* lowers your risk of hitting this error.